# Call a module's multiprocessing function from a script

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

My module, which is also a script, calls some internally defined functions that use multiprocessing.

Running the module as a script works just fine on Windows and Linux. Calling its main function from another python script works fine on Linux but not on Windows.

The core, multi-processed function (the function passed to the `multiprocessing.Process` constructor as the `target`) never gets executed when my module calls the Process's `start()` function.

The module must be doing something too demanding for this usage (multiprocessing on Windows when called from a script), but how can I get to the source of this problem?

Here's some example code to demonstrate the behavior.  First the module:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'my_mp_module.py'

import argparse
import itertools
import Queue
import multiprocessing


def meaty_function(**kwargs):
    'Do a meaty calculation using multiprocessing'

    task_values = kwargs['task_values']

    # Set up a queue of tasks to perform, one for each element in the task_values array
    in_queue  = multiprocessing.Queue()
    out_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    reduce(lambda a, b: a or b,
           itertools.imap(in_queue.put, enumerate(task_values)))

    core_procargs=(
                    in_queue ,
                    out_queue,
                    )
    core_processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=_core_function,
                                              args=core_procargs) for ii in xrange(len(task_values))]
    for p in core_processes:
        p.daemon = True # I've tried both ways, setting this to True and False
        p.start()

    sum_of_results = 0
    for result_count in xrange(len(task_values)):
        a_result = out_queue.get(block=True)
        sum_of_results += a_result
    for p in core_processes:
        p.join()

    return sum_of_results


def _core_function(inp_queue, out_queue):
    'Perform the core calculation for each task in the input queue, placing the results in the output queue'
    while 1:
        try:
            task_idx, task_value = inp_queue.get(block=False)
            # Perform a calculation with this task value.
            task_result = task_idx + task_value # The real calculation is more complicated than this
            out_queue.put(task_result)

        except Queue.Empty:
            break


def get_command_line_arguments(command_line=None):
    'parse the given command_line (list of strings) or from sys.argv, return the corresponding argparse.Namespace object'
    aparse = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    aparse.add_argument('--task_values', '-t',
                        action='append',
                        type=int,
                        help='''The value for each task to perform.''')
    return aparse.parse_args(args=command_line)


def main(command_line=None):
    'perform a meaty calculation with the input from the command line, and print the results'

    # collect input from the command line
    args=get_command_line_arguments(command_line)
    keywords = vars(args)

    # perform a meaty calculation with the input
    meaty_results = meaty_function(**keywords)

    # display the results
    print(meaty_results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    main(command_line=None)
```

Now the script that calls the module:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'my_mp_script.py:'

import my_mp_module
import multiprocessing

multiprocessing.freeze_support()
my_mp_module.main(command_line=None)
```

Running the module as a script gives the expected results:

```
C:\Users\greg>python -m my_mp_module  -t 0 -t 1 -t 2
6
```

But running another script that simply calls the module's `main()` function gives an error message under Windows (here I stripped out the error message duplicated from each of the multiple processes):

```
C:\Users\greg>python my_mp_script.py  -t 0 -t 1 -t 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\greg\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2-64\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Users\greg\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2-64\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 510, in prepare
    '__parents_main__', file, path_name, etc
  File "C:\Users\greg\Documents\PythonCode\Scripts\my_mp_script.py", line 7, in <module>
    my_mp_module.main(command_line=None)
  File "C:\Users\greg\Documents\PythonCode\Lib\my_mp_module.py", line 72, in main
    meaty_results = meaty_function(**keywords)
  File "C:\Users\greg\Documents\PythonCode\Lib\my_mp_module.py", line 28, in meaty_function
    p.start()
  File "C:\Users\greg\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2-64\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\greg\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2-64\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 258, in __init__
    cmd = get_command_line() + [rhandle]
  File "C:\Users\greg\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2-64\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 358, in get_command_line
    is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.''')
RuntimeError:
            Attempt to start a new process before the current process
            has finished its bootstrapping phase.

            This probably means that you are on Windows and you have
            forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

                if __name__ == '__main__':
                    freeze_support()
                    ...

            The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
            is not going to be frozen to produce a Windows executable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux and Windows work a little differently in the way they create additional processes.  Linux `forks` the code but Windows creates a new Python interpreter to run the spawned process.  The effect here is that all your code gets re-loaded just as if it were the first time.  There is a similar question that might be informative to look at see... [How to stop multiprocessing in python running for the full script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306228/how-to-stop-multiprocessing-in-python-running-for-the-full-script#comment83598182_48306228).

The solution here is to modify the `my_mp_script.py` script so the call to `my_mp_module.main()` is guarded like so..

```
import my_mp_module
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_mp_module.main(command_line=None)
```

Note that I've also removed the `freeze_support()` functions for now, however those may be acceptable to put back in if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  At your suggestion, I've edited the example my_mp_module.py in the question to move `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` to just after the `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement.  Alas, this makes no difference in the behavior -- same error message when running the external script.  My real code does not call `freeze_support()` anywhere, but I put it (and leave in) in the example module and script to help illustrate that it already follows the error message's recommendation about `freeze_support()`.

Comment: I would suggest in `my_mp_script.py` putting all the code under an `if __name__` and also try completely removing the `if __name__` from your `my_mp_module.py`.  If that doesn't work I'm not sure where your errors are coming from and unfortunately I don't have Windows setup myself to test this.

Comment: In `my_mp_script.py` put the call to `my_mp_module.main(command_line=None)` under an `if __name__ == '__main__':`.  That worked for me.  I can run your script in windows and it gives the same results as the `my_mp_module.py` (note that I also removed the `freeze` commands`)

Comment: Thank you!  I confirm that that suggestion works on my system as well.  And it's an acceptable solution for me.  If you want to post your comments as an Answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Thanks.  I just edited the original answer so it has the final solution is a bit more succinct.